# Is the Rockstar Editor available on PS4/Xbox One or only PC?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, ps4

I have Grand Theft Auto V on the PlayStation 3, but obviously, I know the Rockstar Editor is not available on the 7th generation of consoles.

I am considering re-buying GTA V on the PlayStation 4. The main reason is to get access to the R* Editor, but I do not actually know if it is on the PS4 as well as the PC or just on the PC, so my question is: Is it, or is it not on 8th gen?

Comment: Why the - ratings? Nothing is wrong with this question.

Comment: And part of my question has been removed, so now I have to make another damn question.

Comment: For one, do you wish to know if the editor is included, or what the core game differences are? You are suppose to ask two seperate questions for two seperate questions. Asking two in the one is a valid close reason. For two, grammar and spelling go a long way. Typing R* instead of rockstar will get you downvotes. We reward good grammar and punctuation, not laziness. Finally, this shows no research effort. That is another valid reason for downvoting, and the reason I did, aswell.

Comment: It was removed because it's too broad.  We're not here for wiki-type answers.  We've kept the question we can actually answer.

Comment: Close Voters, this is not a recommendation question. User is asking if a version of the game comes with its editor.

Comment: As per @Timelord64's comment, please see this meta: [Asking if a game-related-product is available, at all, anywhere, for anyone](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8389/28182)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Rockstar Editor was released for the Xbox One and Playstation 4 versions of GTA V in the 1.29 patch on 21st September 2015.

Source: http://www.christianpost.com/news/grand-theft-auto-5-1-29-update-news-freemode-and-rockstar-editor-added-video-145749/

Comment: If my answer helped you, accept it by clicking the tick next to it. We'll both get rep that way.